# How do i embed mpeg-dash live video stream using this code?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a working code to embed a Wowza manifest.mpd live video stream into a MPEG-dash player on a website but in order for it to work, you have to put in the URL to the manifest file and then click connect.

I need to get rid of the input box and just have it load the manifest file automatically on page load.

I've tried adding the src to the video tag as the manifest URL but it doesn't load. I'm guessing that when clicking connects to load the manifest file the script is also doing something else but with no scripting knowledge I don't know what.

Can anyone suggest what I would change the code to so that it will load the script as it does when you click connect but automatically on page load?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>MPEG-DASH Player - Live Video Streaming</title>

    <script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wowza.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Libraries -->

    <script src="app/lib/jquery/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <!-- https://github.com/kriskowal/q -->
    <script src="app/lib/q.js"></script>

    <!-- https://github.com/creynders/dijon-framework -->
    <script src="app/lib/dijon.js"></script>

    <!-- Misc Libs -->
    <script src="app/lib/xml2json.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/objectiron.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/long.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/Math.js"></script>

    <!-- Player -->
    <script src="app/js/streaming/MediaPlayer.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/Context.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/ErrorHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/Capabilities.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/Debug.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/VideoModel.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/SegmentRequest.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/ManifestLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/ManifestUpdater.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/ManifestModel.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/MediaSourceExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/SourceBufferExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/VideoModelExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/BufferExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/FragmentController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/AbrController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/FragmentLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/Stream.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/BufferController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/rules/SwitchRequest.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/rules/DownloadRatioRule.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/rules/InsufficientBufferRule.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/rules/LimitSwitchesRule.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/rules/BaseRulesCollection.js"></script>

    <!-- Metrics -->
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/MetricsList.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/MetricsModel.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/BufferLevel.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/HTTPRequest.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/PlayList.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/RepresentationSwitch.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/TCPConnection.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/streaming/vo/metrics/DroppedFrames.js"></script>

    <!-- Dash -->
    <script src="app/js/dash/Dash.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashContext.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/vo/Segment.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashParser.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/BaseURLExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/FragmentExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashManifestExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashMetricsExtensions.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/dash/DashMetricsConverter.js"></script>

    <!-- App -->
    <!--script src="app/js/main.js"></script-->

    <!-- Framework CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wowza.css" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        function supports_media_source()
        {
            "use strict";
            var hasWebKit = (window.WebKitMediaSource !== null && window.WebKitMediaSource !== undefined),
                hasMediaSource = (window.MediaSource !== null && window.MediaSource !== undefined);
            return (hasWebKit || hasMediaSource);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="span-18">
            <h1>Live Video Streaming</h1>
            <h2>MPEG-DASH Player</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="span-6 last">
            <img src="img/wowza-logo_1024.png" class="logo" style="height:72px;width:205px" />
        </div>
        <hr class="heading">
        <!-- END HEADER -->


        <!-- EXAMPLE PLAYER: WIDTH of this player should be 630px, height will vary depending on the example-->
        <div class="span-16">
            <div id="supported" style="display:none">
                <div>
                    <style>
                        video {
                            background-color: #000000;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <video id="videoObj" x-webkit-airplay="allow" controls alt="Example File" width="630" height="354" onerror="failed(event)" src="http://undergroundsoundz.com:1935/uszlive/myStream/manifest.mpd"></video>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button id="playObj" type="button" style="width:50px" onclick="JavaScript:playControl()" disabled="disabled">Pause</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <b>Stream:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="connectStr" size = "56" type="text" placeholder="" value="http://undergroundsoundz.com:1935/uszlive/myStream/manifest.mpd"/>
                            <button id="connectObj" type="button" style="width:80px" onclick="JavaScript:connect()">Connect</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <b>Status:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="statusStr" size = "100" type="text" placeholder="" value="">Disconnected</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="debug_log" style="height: 425px; width: 630px; overflow: auto; clear: both;">
            </div>
        <script>
            if ( supports_media_source() ) {
                supported.style.display="";
                videoObj.style.display="";
            }
            else {
                notsupported.style.display="";
            }
            var player;
            function connect()
            {
                if(connectObj.textContent == "Disconnect") {
                    if(player!=null)
                        player.stop();
                    videoObj.src = null;
                    videoObj.load();
                    connectObj.textContent = "Connect";
                    playObj.disabled = "disabled";
                    playObj.textContent = "Pause";
                    statusStr.textContent = "Disconnected";
                }
                else {
                    connectObj.textContent = "Disconnect";
                    playObj.disabled = "";
                    playObj.textContent = "Pause";
                    statusStr.textContent = "Playing";
                    var video = document.querySelector("video"),
                        context = new Dash.di.DashContext();

                    player = new MediaPlayer(context);
                    player.startup();

                    debug = player.debug;
                    //debug.init(console);

                    player.autoPlay = true;
                    player.attachView(video);

                    player.setIsLive(true);
                    player.attachSource(connectStr.value);
                }
            }
            function playControl() {
                if (videoObj.paused == false) {
                    videoObj.pause();
                    statusStr.textContent = "Paused";
                    playObj.textContent = "Play";
                } 
                else {
                    videoObj.play();
                    statusStr.textContent="Playing";
                    playObj.textContent = "Pause";
                }
            }
            function failed(e) {
                // video playback failed - show a message saying why
                switch (e.target.error.code) {
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
                    statusStr.textContent='You aborted the video playback.';
                    break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
                    statusStr.textContent='A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.';
                    break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
                    statusStr.textContent='The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.';
                    break;
                    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                    statusStr.innerHTML= 'The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.<br/>';
                    statusStr.innerHTML+= '<span style="color:red;">Please close all tabs and then try running the appropriate <span style="font-style:italic;">LaunchDashPlayer</span> script for your system in your \"examples/LiveVideoStreaming/MPEGDASHPlayer\" folder.</span>';
                    break;
                    default:
                    statusStr.textContent = 'An unknown error occurred.';
                    break;
                }
            }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: here is a link to the example, live stream isn't running but you can see what happens: http://www.undergroundsoundz.com/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/MPEGDASHPlayer/player.html

Comment: by the way the player will only load in chrome